# Wordpress issue: after migration only homepage works

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, vps, httpd.conf

A few days ago I tried transferring my `wordpress` website from shared hosting to `vps` but I've run into a problem.

After following many guides/tutorials and googling myself I can't figure out why it's not working. The homepage is the only page that loads all other pages 404. I've included some relevant files.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[HTACCESS](http://pastebin.com/dYgtc11G)

[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/pH2XQ3Vp)

Partial directory listing - www.pastebin.com/BCPfRisB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25):

1. Login to your wp-admin
2. Go to Settings > Permalinks
3. Don't make any changes, just click "Save Changes" button.

Your site's secondary page would work now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work. i have also tried to do this while the htaccess file was removed ... no success. any more sugestions?

Comment: Hey This works for me. Thank you very much :D
First I did was removed the htaccess and follow this steps and it works.

Comment: still saving people time in 2023 :-)

Comment: Thanks man. Mine worked.

Answer (score 13):

I too have the same issue, fixed it creating [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) in the root directory with following content:

**/var/www/html/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Along with editing `httpd.conf` placed in `/etc/httpd/conf` to set value of [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive to `All` for the `/var/www/html` directory, as below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And finally restarting apache:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

For all the steps related to deployment you can find here - [Hosting WordPress Application on Centos Box](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2017/05/20/hosting-wordpress-application-on-an-ec2-instance-aws/).

Comment: For someone hosting on Debian (mine was 10 at time of writing) `httpd.conf` is named `apache2.conf` and is located in `/etc/apache2/`

Answer (score 8):

I posted this answer because I didn't find an answer which offered **all possible solutions**. Consider this answer as a *pleasant* checklist which should help you to fix this issue.

a) Permalinks update. The following steps *rebuild* the internal settings.

> a) Login to your WordPress dashboard.
> b) Go to Settings -> Permalinks.
> c) Don't make any changes, just click "Save Changes" button.

---

b) `.htaccess` needs the settings for the rewrite engine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

c) Also, due to an error in the Apache log file the following entry was needed as well in the `your-wordpress.conf` Apache file which is mostly in the `/etc/apache2/vhostd.d` directory.

```
<Directory your-wordpress-directory>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

d) Assure `mod_rewrite` is enabled

```
a2enmod rewrite
Restart Apache
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to this issues.

[Wordpress 404 error on every page except homepage (After migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476927/wordpress-404-error-on-every-page-except-homepage-after-migration/42478180#42478180)

There is a wp plugin call 'duplicator',  you can use it for small sites,
else 
you should change the wp_options table siteurl and home url, then login to admin back end -> settings -> permalinks - set the permalinks and save,

Then you can set the .htaccess just set following code and test.

```
`#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your home and site url to the new url you moved to. The easiest way to do that would be to add this

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

to your wp-config.php 
Just make sure to exchange the dummy links with your new website URL. Let me know if this helps.